# Deriving a Restricted Mean Matrix for Matrix variate data

Tags: probability-distributions, statistical-inference, matrix-calculus

I am working with Matrix variate data using the EM algorithm.

Deriving the E-step and M-step is straightforward under this setting. Now, I am interested in deriving a restricted mean matrix in the M-step.

Assuming the first column of the mean matrix is fixed at the same value while the other elements vary.

Finally, how can one derive the $\frac{\partial \mathbf{Q}(\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial \mathbf{M}^{\star}}$  and $\frac{\partial \mathbf{Q}(\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial a}$

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\size#1{\op{size}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\Sj{\sum_{j=\o}^m}
\def\Sk{\sum_{k=\o}^n}
\def\Skk{\sum_{\c{k=2}}^n}
$Consider the following variables and their dimensions
$$\eqalign{
p,q &= \size{a}
\;=\; \size{b} \;=\; \size{M_{jk}}
\\
m,\o &= \size{u_j} \qquad \{ {\rm standard\;basis\;vector} \} \\
n,\o &= \size{v_k} \qquad \{ {\rm standard\;basis\;vector} \} \\
p,p &= \size{I_p} \qquad \{ {\rm identity\;matrix} \} \\
mp,nq &= \size{M}
\\
}$$
Matrix analogs of the standard basis vectors can be constructed as
$$\eqalign{
U_j &= \LR{u_j\otimes I_p} \in\bbR{mp\times p}
\;&\implies\;
  U_j^TU_k = \delta_{jk}I_p
\\
V_k &= \LR{v_k\otimes I_q} \in\bbR{nq\times q}
\;&\implies\;
  V_j^TV_k = \delta_{jk}I_q
\\
}$$
and can be used to partition the $M$ matrix
$$\eqalign{
&M_{jk} = U_j^TMV_k
\\
&M = \Sj\Sk\: U_jM_{jk}V_k^T = \m{
M_{\o\o}&M_{\o 2}&\ldots&M_{\o n} \\
M_{2\o}&M_{22}&\ldots&M_{2n} \\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\
M_{m\o}&M_{m2}&\ldots&M_{mn} \\
}
\\
}$$
The Frobenius product $(:)$ is extremely useful in *Matrix Calculus*
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \Sj\Sk A_{jk}B_{jk} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \} \\
A:B &= B:A \qquad \{ {\rm commutes} \} \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \;\;\; \{ {\rm transposes} \} \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A \;=\, \LR{A^TC}:B \\
}$$
Finally, the $Q$-function can be written as
$$\eqalign{
X &= \LR{M-Y},\quad
P = P^T = \Psi^{-1},\quad
S = S^T = \Sigma^{-1} \\
Q &= -\tfrac12S:\LR{XPX^T} \\
}$$
Its *differential* with respect to $M$ can be calculated as
$$\eqalign{
dQ &= -\tfrac12S:\LR{dX\:PX^T+XP\:dX^T} \\
 &= -S:\LR{dX\:PX^T} \\
 &= -\LR{SXP}:dX \\
 &= -\LR{SXP}:dM \\
}$$
and with respect to a single partition $M_{jk}$ as
$$\eqalign{
dQ &= -\LR{SXP}:\LR{U_j\,dM_{jk}\,V_k^T} \\
 &= -\LR{U_j^TSXPV_k}:dM_{jk} \\
}$$
From this result, the requested *gradient* is seen to be
$$\eqalign{
\grad{Q}{M_{jk}} &= -{U_j^TSXPV_k} \qquad \qquad \qquad \\
}$$
The other gradient merely omits the first block column from consideration
$$\eqalign{
\grad{Q}{M^*} &= -\Sj\Skk {U_j^TSXPV_k} \qquad \qquad \\
}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. There are 2 things I want to make sure that they are clear
- the $M_{jk}$ is a scalar. Thus, M is a matrix of (p x q) where its elements are scalars
- I need to enforce the restriction that the scalars are equal in the first column of the mean matrix M (i.e. $m_{11} = m_{21}$ )

Comment: No, $M_{jk}$ is a $(p\times q)$ matrix. It is a single block of the full $M$ matrix. For example $a = M_{11},\:b = M_{12},\:etc$

Comment: In my case, $M_{jk}$ is a scalar. Thus, $a$ is a scalar, $b$ is also a scalar. 
I believe that would make the derivation much easier. 

Also, how to enforce that restriction above and deriving the gradient with respect to the scalar $a$?